# Express Throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a nodejs server running the common framework express. I have noticed recently that when I make requests from my server, I get this error at seemingly random times, for example, if I were to make a request twice, the error would usually only happen the first request, and not the second. I'm having trouble pinpointing what is causing this error, because I often write my code in one go, then test it later. Here is the error in full:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
    at json (/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:256:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise' Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
      at json (/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:256:18)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) }
```

All that I can tell from this error is that it may involve some reference to "app", however I am not sure what it could be specifically, as I haven't changed anything pertaining to "app" in express recently. Here is my express configuration on my server file:

```
    const express = require('express'),
        user = require('./routers/User.js'),
        helmet = require('helmet'),
        app = express();
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.set('trust proxy', true);

    //map router files to respective urls
    //these are stored in a directory and set above, these contain all of the handlers for each of my routes
    app.use('/user', user);

    //set port and listen on it
    app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server running on port 5000"));
```

If anything else is needed of me, please ask. I've tried to include every reference pertaining to the word "app" in my code, but that may not be enough.

EDIT: I thank you all for trying to help, but the code I provided was not intended to work, it was simply an example of what I import, this is an error with express, and I'm just trying to find out what kind of behavior would cause it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

for your code to work you have to add

```
const express = require('express'),
        user = require('./routers/User.js'),
        helmet = require('helmet')
 ----> const app = express();

or helmet = require('helmet'), <-----
 app = express()
```

Comment: that was an oversight in the question, not an actual error, sorry.

Comment: can you check my edited answer and see if it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing a comma after "helmet = require('helmet')

```
const express = require('express'),
    user = require('./routers/User.js'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('trust proxy', true);

//map router files to respective urls
//these are stored in a directory and set above, these contain all of the handlers for each of my routes
app.use('/user', user);

//set port and listen on it
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server running on port 5000"));
```

Answer (score -1):

//Worked fine for me. removed ur local import. This runs fine.

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('trust proxy', true);
//set port and listen on it
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server running on port 5000"));
```